# How to get the column value of the selected row in wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

In my listview, I've three columns, the first column is displayed as text with image and the rest of the columns just text only. The listview is coded as below:

```
<TabItem x:Name="HistoryTab" Header="History" Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}">
  <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="HistoryTabLv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="164" Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="HistoryTabLv_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="TimeColumn" Header="Time" Width="85">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,0,0,0">
                  <Image x:Name="Img" Height="12" Width="12" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="PhoneNumColumn" Header="Phone Number" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNum}" />
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="DirectionColumn" Header="Direction" Width="95" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Direction}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

If the action statement is true, the relevant data will be binded to each column as coded below.

```
private void HistoryTabLv_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myStatement == true)
    {
         var uri = new Uri(@"/Resources/time.png", UriKind.Relative);
         myImg = new BitmapImage(uri);
         DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now;
         HistoryTabLv.Items.Insert(0, new { Image = myImg, Time = myTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"), PhoneNum = calledNum,
                    Direction = "Called out" }); 
    }
}
```

In winform, if I want to get the second column value of the selected row, it is coded like this: (based on what I've searched)

```
string secondCol = lv.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
```

I want to get the second column value of the selected row (in my case is the PhoneNum column), how can I do that in WPF. I tried with the code below but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
string myText = (string)((DataRowView)HistoryTabLv.SelectedItems[0])["PhoneNum"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF `ListViewItem` is just a wrapper for your content object and `SelectedItem(s)` will be of the same type as item in your source collection so normally you would cast `HistoryTabLv.SelectedItem` to that type but because, as far as I can see, you use anonymous type it makes it a bit more difficult. I think the easiest way is around your problem is to use [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

```
dynamic selectedItem = HistoryTabLv.SelectedItem;
var phoneNum = selectedItem.PhoneNum;
```

or

```
dynamic selectedItem = HistoryTabLv.SelectedItems[0];
var phoneNum = selectedItem.PhoneNum;
```

**EDIT**

If you would create class for you item like

```
public class MyItemClass {
    public string Image  { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNum { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
}
```

and create your item like

```
new MyItemClass { 
    Image = myImg, 
    Time = myTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"), 
    PhoneNum = calledNum,
    Direction = "Called out" 
}
```

then you could cast `SelectedItem(s)` to your item class like

```
var selectedItem = (MyItemType)HistoryTabLv.SelectedItem
```

Comment: Hi @dkozl, thanks for your answer, it works well for me. By the way, can you explain what is anonymous type in my case? How to make easier to implement?

Comment: When you add new item you do `new { Image = ..., Time = ..., PhoneNum = ..., Direction = ... }` which means you create [anonymous object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx) with 4 properties. You could create class type with these 4 properties and use that to create new items (like `new MyItemType { Image = ..., Time = ..., PhoneNum = ..., Direction = ... }`), then it would be easier to cast to that type like (`var selectedItem = (MyItemType)HistoryTabLv.SelectedItem;`)